# C#/SQLServer Database Connections in multithreaded environment

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, wcf, database-connection

I have a multithreaded application.Each thread will be responsible for uploading data to a SQL Database.My question is that, what is the correct solution to do this? Each thread shall open its own new db connection or some singleton pattern shall be used for creating database. Or please let me know if there is any other best approach for this. Any code sample will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you to create a new `SqlConnection` in all your threads, as SQL server and DBProvider will use the connection pooling, which will perform faster than your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to open multiple connections to call your WCF service multiple times at once. All you have to do is to use an asynchronous way to call it.
You can for example use Parrallel.ForEach() instead of creating your own threads.

```
public void UploadData(List<Data> allDataToUpload)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(allDataToUpload, data =>
    {
        _yourService.Upload(data);
    });
}
```

Also, if you are not VERY familiar with threading, I suggest to use all the new tools provided by Microsoft since .net 4.5 like async, await and the library Task instead of managing your own threads.

Comment: Dear Ronan thanks for your reply. I have slightly modified my question. I was talking about db conenctions.

Comment: Dear Ronan thanks for your reply. I have slightly modified my question. I was talking about db conenctions. But your answer has adressed my another issue. Please have a look on updated description and help me for this too.